Gradle Task Fails with IllegalArgumentException: identity-provider not found
I am working on a Gradle task that fetches a GraphQL schema and saves it to a file. The task needs to load configuration details from a YAML file (application-dev.yml). However, I keep encountering an error that says "identity-provider not found". I'm using the SnakeYAML library to parse the YAML file.
Here is the relevant code in my build.gradle.kts:
// Load configuration from YAML
fun loadConfig(): Map<String, String> {
    val yaml = Yaml()
    val inputStream = FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application-dev.yml")
    val data: Map<String, Any> = yaml.load(inputStream)
    println("Data loaded from YAML: $data")

    val customsConfig = data["customs"] as? Map<*, *> ?: run {
        println("Customs key not found or not a map!")
        throw IllegalArgumentException("customs not found")
    }
    println("Customs Config: $customsConfig")

    val identityProviderConfig = customsConfig["identity-provider"] as? Map<*, *> ?: run {
        println("Identity-provider key not found or not a map!")
        throw IllegalArgumentException("identity-provider not found")
    }
    println("Identity Provider Config: $identityProviderConfig")

    val tokenConfig = identityProviderConfig["token"] as? Map<*, *> ?: run {
        println("Token key not found or not a map!")
        throw IllegalArgumentException("token not found")
    }
    println("Token Config: $tokenConfig")

    return tokenConfig as Map<String, String>
}

// Task to fetch GraphQL schema
tasks.register("fetchSchema") {
    doLast {
        try {
            println("Loading configuration...")
            val config = loadConfig()
            val clientId = config["client-id"] ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("client-id not found")
            val clientSecret = config["client-secret"] ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("client-secret not found")
            val token = fetchToken(clientId, clientSecret)
            println("Token fetched: $token")
            println("Fetching GraphQL Schema...")
            fetchGraphQLSchema("https://xxx-data.api.dev.xxx.com/graphql", token, "src/main/resources/schema2.graphql")
            println("Schema has been fetched successfully.")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("An error occurred: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}


And here is the application-dev.yml content:
customs:
  bridge:
    public-url: http://localhost:8080
  security:
    post:
      user:
        creation:
          enabled: false
  multi-tenancy:
    enabled: true
    default:
      maxPoolSize: 10
      minIdle: 0
      connectionTimeout: 5000
      idleTimeout: 20000
      maxLifetime: 600000
      driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  identity-provider:
    token:
      url: https://login.dev.XXX.com/connect/token
      client-id: placeholder_client_id
      tenant-id: placeholder_tenant_id
      scope: placeholder_scope
      client-secret: placeholder_client_secret


I tried to load the YAML configuration and fetch a token using the fetchSchema task. I expected the task to load the configuration successfully and proceed to fetch the GraphQL schema. However, I encountered an error indicating that the "identity-provider" key was not found or not a map.
The console output is as follows:
> Task :fetchSchema
Loading configuration...
Data loaded from YAML: {server={port=8080, allow={origin=*}, tomcat={max-swallow-size=10MB}}, spring={sql={init-mode=never}, output={ansi={enabled=always}}, resources={cache-period=60000, chain={cache=true, enabled=true}}, thymeleaf={cache=false}, ...
Identity-provider key not found or not a map!
An error occurred: identity-provider not found


Could someone help me identify what might be wrong with my configuration loading logic or my YAML file?
